# nodejs formidable incomingform radio buttons

Tags: node.js

okay so i have this nodejs file that now can display my main html page that has a form on it with nothing but radio buttons. i have yet to find a source that can explain how to pass the radio buttons that are pressed on to a new html page.i am currently trying to use formidable

```
function onRequestStats(req, res){
    console.log("Getting form data ");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

        )
```

the data in questio are 8 questiosn with 5 buttons each, i have them set so only 1 can answer each question. how can i pull that data?

Comment: node.js is server-side, you're talking about client side...

Comment: nodejs. is supposed to save the input